Spring Boot Security migrating mvcMatchers to spring boot 3
SecurityFilterChain unsecuredResources(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity //
            .requestMatchers((matchers) -> matchers 
                    .mvcMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/guid") 
                    .mvcMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/check-mpan")) 
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->   authorize.anyRequest().permitAll());
    return httpSecurity.build();
}

How do I migrate this to spring boot 3?
I have tried the following, but it does not work.
httpSecurity
    .authorizeHttpRequests(matchers -> matchers
       .requestMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/guid").permitAll()
       .requestMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/check-mpan").permitAll())
    .authorizeHttpRequests(matchers -> matchers
       .anyRequest().permitAll())


Please modify your description, you didn't mention anything about authentication.

You just need this :
For authentication you also need to add another filter.
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain additionalSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/**")
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/guid").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/v1/api/smartmeter/hb/check-mpan").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }
}


There is already a SecurityFilterChain in the classpath and I want to add a new SecurityFilterchain to allow those 2 additional endpoints. When I implement the suggestion above,  no endpoints requires authentication anymore. I still want the secured endpoints to the authenticated to access.

@GauravShah in your description you didn't mention anything about authentication.  You mentioned migration, anyway i modified my answered to match authentication too.
Please check it.
